# Python: Concatenate url with a integer

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm new in python and I'm trying to concatenate an url with an integer but i get this error:

> - TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects*

My code looks like this:

```
for x in range(0,10):
   url = "http:www.eluniversal.com.mx/minuto-x-minuto?seccion=All&page="+(x)
   x +=1
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: since you are new, you should read about python a bit. Use str(x)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python is a dynamically [**strongly** typed](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Why%20is%20Python%20a%20dynamic%20language%20and%20also%20a%20strongly%20typed%20language) langauge. So it won't convert an integer to string when you try to concatenate them.

You have to either use string interpolation or explicitly convert it to an string.

```
url = "http:www.eluniversal.com.mx/minuto-x-minuto?seccion=All&page=%s" % x

url = "http:www.eluniversal.com.mx/minuto-x-minuto?seccion=All&page=" + str(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
url = "http:www.eluniversal.com.mx/minuto-x-minuto?seccion=All&page="+str(x)
```

Add a "str" in front of your brackets and it will work. By doing this you can convert the int into a string.

Answer (score 0):

`url += str(x)`

`x+=1` has no effect.